# Slideshow won't append to div

Tags: jquery, html, slick.js

I'm creating a slideshow of specific projects for one of my clients. When the button is clicked it's supposed to append the slideshow with all the correct images to the div with id"slideshow". For some reason when I click the button nothing happens. Can someone look at my code and see what could possibly be wrong?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Black Pro Pix | Professional Photography
        </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="blackpropixfallen.css">
        <!-- Satisfy Google Font -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Slick Carousel -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>




    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class = "reveal">
                      <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                      <img  src="" id = "mimg" class = "modalimg" width = "100%" height = "auto">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "slideshow">

        </div>

                    <div class = "hiddenfigures" style = "display:none" >
                      <div class = "slickcarousel">
                        <img src = "Fallengallery/IMG_4553.jpg">
                        <img src = "Fallengallery/Interconnected.jpg">
                        <img src = "Fallengallery/LifeLongLies pt.2 (yellow).jpg">
                        <img src = "Fallengallery/Mornin' Murderin' Marauder (abstract).jpg">
                        <img src = "Fallengallery/Mornin' Murderin' Marauder (Red).jpg">
                        <img src = "Fallengallery/Nightfall (vibrant).jpg">
                        <img src = "Fallengallery/Paris 15.jpg">
                        <img src = "Fallengallery/Paris 18.jpg">
                        <img src = "Fallengallery/Somebody's Watching.jpg">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "container-fluid">
                      <div class = "row">
                        <div class = "col-xs-12">
                          <button class = "hiddenf">
                            Hidden Figures
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.slickcarousel').slick({
                autoplay: true,
                slidesToShow: 4,
                variableWidth: true,
                centerMode: true,
                nextArrow: "<span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'>",
                prevArrow: "<span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left'>",
                slidesToScroll: 1

              });
              $("img").click(function(){
                var sr=$(this).attr('src');
                $('#mimg').attr('src',sr);
                $("#myModal").modal(); 
              });
              displayHiddenf();

            });
            function displayHiddenf() {
                $(".hiddenf").click(function() {
                    $("#slideshow").empty();
                    $(".hiddenfigures").appendTo("#slideshow");
                });

  </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can replace you code with this.***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function runSlideShow() {
        $('.slickcarousel').slick({
            autoplay: true,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            variableWidth: true,
            centerMode: true,
            nextArrow: "<span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'>",
            prevArrow: "<span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left'>",
            slidesToScroll: 1
        });
    }
    $(".hiddenf").click(function(){
        $('.hiddenfigures').css('display','block');
        runSlideShow();
    });
    $("img").click(function(){
        var sr=$(this).attr('src');
        $('#mimg').attr('src',sr);
        $("#myModal").modal(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="reveal">
                <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                <img  src="" id = "mimg" class = "modalimg" width = "100%" height = "auto">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="hiddenfigures" style="display:none">
        <div class = "slickcarousel">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any">
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/150/any">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-xs-12">
            <button class = "hiddenf">
                Hidden Figures
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome @Breevie.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `<div>` hiddenfigures the style attribute persists. Try removing the `style=display:none;` in your js-method

Answer (score 0):

remove display: none;

delete the div

$( "#slideshow" ).wrap( "" );